# How do I control Finder and App Store notifications in OS X?

Tags: macos, notifications

Notification Center in OS X (10.9, Mavericks) provides a way to control configure notifications for various Apps such as Mail or Safari, but seems to provide on settings for controlling notifications from Finder (e.g., improperly ejected drives) and the App Store (e.g., the availability of updates).

How can I control Finder and App Store notifications in OS X?

Comment: By controlling you mean what?

Comment: Adjusting setting as I can for other things (what appears in Notification Center, how a notification is presented, etc.).